# Map ctrl+key different from typing key in xkb or xmodmap

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap

Is it possible to map ctrl+key different from regular typing key in linux?
I have done it in windows with MSKLC but can't figure out how to do it in linux. E.g. I want to type dvorak but have regular ctrl+c etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible with XKB but I can't tell you how. It probably involves groups.